# Sort the Values in a Stack

Tags: sorting, stack

[image]

[image]

Hi, this is a simple exercise and here is one of the answer code:

```
class CheckSort {
public static void sortStack(Stack<Integer> stack) {
    //1. Use a second tempStack.
    //2. Pop value from mainStack.
    //3. If the value is greater or equal to the top of tempStack, then push the value in tempStack
    //else pop all values from tempStack and push them in mainStack and in the end push value in tempStack and repeat from step 2.
    //till mainStack is not empty.
    //4. When mainStack will be empty, tempStack will have sorted values in descending order.
    //5. Now transfer values from tempStack to mainStack to make values sorted in ascending order.
    Stack<Integer> newStack = new Stack<>(stack.getMaxSize());
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        Integer value = stack.pop();
        if (!newStack.isEmpty() && value >= newStack.top()) {
            newStack.push(value);
        } else {
            while (!newStack.isEmpty() && newStack.top() > value)
                stack.push(newStack.pop());
            newStack.push(value);
        }
    }
    while (!newStack.isEmpty())
        stack.push(newStack.pop());
}
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>(7);
    stack.push(2);
    stack.push(97);
    stack.push(4);
    stack.push(42);
    stack.push(12);
    stack.push(60);
    stack.push(23);
    sortStack(stack);
    while(!stack.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println(stack.pop());
    }
}
```

}

I don't understand this part:

```
} else {
            while (!newStack.isEmpty() && newStack.top() > value)
                stack.push(newStack.pop());
            newStack.push(value);
```

So when the top element in the new stack is greater than the original stack, we push the value from the new stack to the original stack and then push the value back to the new stack ??
I am totally lost here!! Could someone help me explain this part? Thanks a looooot!!!

Comment: Another meaningless assignment. As soon as you sort a stack it is no longer a stack. I would complain to the teaching staff about this.

Answer (score 0):

The code only needs the else part, and this simpler version is faster if there are a lot of duplicate values. I didn't find any data patterns where this simpler version was slower then the code in the question.

```
    public static void sortStack(Stack<Integer> stack) {
        Stack<Integer> newStack = new Stack<>();
        Integer value;
        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            value = stack.pop();
            while (!newStack.isEmpty() && newStack.peek() > value)
               stack.push(newStack.pop());
            newStack.push(value);
        }
        while (!newStack.isEmpty())
            stack.push(newStack.pop());
    }
```

Link to a C++ example with an explanation.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sort-stack-using-temporary-stack

If two temporary stacks are used, time complexity can be reduced from O(n^2) to O(n log(n)) using polyphase merge sort, but the code is complicated.